# How to externalize common tags from two XSD files

Tags: xml, xsd

It's getting error prone and I don't like it. Can I store the common tags in a third separate XSD?

I have two XSD files that share most of the tag definitions (38 tags). Each file has other unique tags (1 tag and 2 tags), so the files have 39 tags (38 + 1), and 40 tags (38 + 2) respectively.

Every time I edit a common tag I need to make sure I make the same changes on both files the exact same way... and it's not quite easy anymore.

I was wondering if I could store the common tags in a third "common" XSD, and somehow "include" them in both main files.

This is my [simplified] case:

- File "a.xsd":

  ```
  <xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

    <xsd:complexType name="generation-model">
      <xsd:attribute name="base-dir" type="xsd:string" use="required" />
    </xsd:complexType>

    <!-- +38 common tags here -->

  </xsd:schema>
  ```
- File "b.xsd":

  ```
  <xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

    <xsd:complexType name="main-unit">
      <xsd:attribute name="identifier" type="xsd:string" use="required" />
    </xsd:complexType>

    <xsd:complexType name="set">
      <xsd:attribute name="value" type="xsd:string" use="required" />
    </xsd:complexType>

    <!-- +38 common tags here -->

  </xsd:schema>
  ```

Anyway, in case of emergency -- if there's no way of doing this -- I'm considering just concatenating file fragments. Ugly but I guess will work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a third XSD file,that stores the common elements. Then you can use either [Xsd Import](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/el_import.asp) or [XSD Include](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/el_include.asp) to add the common elements to each of the separate two files. 
If the same namespace is used then XSD Include should be used. For a different namespace xsd import is suitable.

An example is available here: [Example](http://www.datypic.com/books/defxmlschema/chapter04.html)

Update based on the comment of The Impaler:
The `include` tags must be **first in place** before the custom tags of the XSD. An approach that works is to move the `include` to the top of the XSD.
Also while using JAXB it was required to implement an `LSResourceResolver` and an `LSInput` to resolve the "external" common XSD resource file, that is actually located inside the single JAR file of the application.

Comment: Thanks. Can you add an example?

Comment: You are welcome, I added a link to an example that looks quite well written.

Comment: Excellent! "include" seems to be what I need (since it's the same namespace). Will try it right away.

Comment: Nice to be of assistance! Let me know if it worked for you.

Comment: It took me an hour to finally test it using JAXB, but `include` works flawlessly. One caveat that is not mentioned in the example is that the `include` tags must be **first in place** before the custom tags of the XSD (you may want to add this to the answer): I moved the `include` to the top and problem solved. Another caveat is that I was forced to implement an `LSResourceResolver` and an `LSInput` to resolve the "external" common XSD resource file, that is actually located inside the single JAR file of my application. All in all worked awesome! Thanks, accepting answer.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. I will add the points you mention in the answer so it can be more helpful in the future.